# IBM DB2 values displayed as utf-8 text

Tags: database, jdbc, utf-8, db2, db2-luw

Once I connect to the database (DB2) to check the values in the tables, if they have special chars then I see their utf-8 text value:

[image]
I expected instead to see the correct: Tükörfúrógép.

I am still able to handle the value properly, but is there any configuration in the db that I am missing to display the value properly when checking the table?

More Info:

Connected to DB with Intellij and also tried with DbVisualizer.

The following JDBC connection was used in intellij:

```
jdbc:db2://(...)?characterEncoding=UTF-8;
```

Tried both with the `characterEncoding` and without getting the same results.

I am still able to handle the value properly, but is there any configuration in the db that I am missing to display the value properly when checking the table?

**DB Version: v11 LUW**

**JDBC: com.ibm.db2.jcc -- db2jcc4 -- Version 10.5**

Encoding being used: UTF-8

> db2 "select char(value,10), char(name,10) from sysibmadm.dbcfg where
> name like 'code%'"
>
> 1          2
> ---------- ---------- 1208       codepage   UTF-8      codeset
>
> 2 record(s) selected.

**UPDATE 1:**

- I was able to directly insert in the database values with special
  chars, so starting to think this is not DB2 configuration missing but
  maybe jdbc or other related issue.

Comment: How do you connect, which tool, which config for char encoding, what is the database encoding? It is a matter of configuration and conversion

Comment: Thanks for the feedback data_henrik, updated the question with the tools used.
Trying to confirm the database encoding. Most of db2 documentation is broken...

Comment: please edit your question to show the output of the following query: `select char(value,10), char(name,10) from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like 'code%'`  , and if you lack permission then ask your DBA or someone with relevant permissions.

Comment: What's the result of `select hex(town) from ...`?

Comment: Thanks @mao, the encoding being used in the database is UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkBaristein the result is 54C383C2BC6BC383C2B67266C383C2BA72C383C2B367C383C2A970

Comment: In my dbvis (v12.0.4) on linux, with Db2 v11.5.5 the correct characters appear for that UTF-8 string, and I get the same hex code as you.  I do not have any property for characterEncoding in the connection string.

Comment: I see, thanks for the extra info @mao. 
Using here dbvis(v10.0.21) and db2(v11.1.0), but in dbvis in the properties of the database which enconding do you have selected?

Answer (score 1):

You must have the following HEX string representation for given string `Tükörfúrógép` in UTF-8 database:
`54C3BC6BC3B67266C3BA72C3B367C3A970`.
But you have the following instead with repeating garbage symbols:
54C3**83C2**BC6BC3**83C2**B67266C3**83C2**BA72C3**83C2**B367C3**83C2**A970

You may try to manually remove such a byte sequence with the following statement, but it's better to understand a root cause of such a garbage appearance in this column.

```
VALUES REPLACE (x'54C383C2BC6BC383C2B67266C383C2BA72C383C2B367C383C2A970', x'83C2', '');
SELECT REPLACE (TOWN, x'83C2', '') FROM ...;
```

Comment: That's a great point, thanks @MarkBaristein, looking into it.
Also I inserted manually some values with specials chars directly in the database and in that case it is correctly stored. Might be some jdbc or other thing adding the "garbage"